# How to extract information from two or more columns into one

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have clients who register for 2 or more classes via a form and the dates appear in separate columns on the form summary page - name in colB, first class date in colD, second class date in colG, etc.
So clients dates of their 1st, 2nd, 3rd classes overlap.

I want to pull the dates into a schedule sheet and can do this easily for the first date (colD). But I cannot figure out how to also pull in the clients for the second class into the same column on the schedule sheet. I can get them into separate columns easily enough, but would like them all to appear in the same column to save space and make the scheduler more easy to view.

This is the code I tried:

```
=QUERY(Form3!B1:M200, "select B, D where C >= date '2015-03-02' and C <= date '2015-03-06'", 1)
```

Is it possible to create a single column list of all clients taking class any particular week regardless of whether it is their 1st 2nd 3rd class?

It means drawing from 3 or more columns and returning all the results to just one column.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=arrayformula({Query(Form3!A1:D20,"Select B where C>=date '2015-03-02' AND C<=date '2015-03-05' ",0);Query(Form3!A1:D20,"Select D where C>=date '2015-03-02' AND C<=date '2015-03-05'",0)})
```